# A proof of the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

This is exercise III.4.15 of Freitag and Busam.

Exercise:
Let $g$ be an analytic function on an open set containing the closed disk $\bar{U}_r(a)$. We assume $|g(a)|<|g(z)| $ for all
$z$ on the boundary of the disk. Then there exists a zero of $g$ in the interior of the disk.

Using this, find a further proof of the Open Mapping Theorem.

Solution:
If $f$ is a non-constant function on a domain $D\supset \bar{U}_r(a)$, then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ with $|f(z)-f(a)|\geq 2\varepsilon$ for $|z-a|=r$. (*)

Then, using the first part of the exercise it is easy to see that $U_\varepsilon (f(a))$ is contained in the image of $f$. (**)

I can prove the first part using the maximum principle, but I don't understand why (* ) is true nor why (* ) and the first part imply (**).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: (*) follows from the fact that $f$ is continuous and the circle is compact, hence, $K:=f(\{z: |z-a|=r\})$ is compact and does not contain $f(a)$, hence, the distance function between $f(a)$ and $K$ attains positive minimum.

Comment: @MoisheCohen But how do we know that K does not contain f(a)?

Comment: See the 2nd sentence of you post.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I don't think they are the same f. Because in the hypothesis of the open mapping theorem, we don't have the assumption in the first part of the exercise.

Comment: The you should make it clear in your question. In any case, since zeroes of nonconstant analytic function are isolated, you can find small $r$ for which $f(a)$ is not in $K$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks!

Comment: $(*)$ is false as stated but we can choose r so that it becomes true. If $D=\mathbb C$, $f(z)=\sin z$ and $r=2\pi$ then $f(2\pi)=f(0)$ which makes $(*)$ false in general.

Comment: $(**)$ is easy: if $|w-f(a)|<\epsilon$ then $|w-f(z)| \geq |f(z)-f(a)| -|f(a)-w| > 2\epsilon -\epsilon >|w-f(a)|$ for $|z-a|=r$ so the first part with $g(z)=f(z)-w$ implies there exists $z$ such that $|z-a| <r$ and $f(z)=w$. Hence $w \in f(U_r (a))$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!